# What are the differences between sc.parallelize and sc.textFile?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am new to Spark. can someone please clear my doubt:

Lets assume below is my code:

```
a = sc.textFile(filename) 
b = a.filter(lambda x: len(x)>0 and x.split("\t").count("111"))
c = b.collect()
```

I hope below is what happens internally: (Please correct if my understanding is wrong)

(1) variable a will be saved as a RDD variable containing the expected txt file content

(2) The driver node breaks up the work into tasks and each task contains information about the split of the data it will operate on. 
    Now these Tasks are assigned to worker nodes.

(3) when collection action (i.e collect() in our case) is invoked, the results will be returned to the master from different nodes, and saved as a local variable c.

Now I want to understand what difference below code makes:

```
a = sc.textFile(filename).collect() 
b = sc.parallelize(a).filter(lambda x: len(x)>0 and x.split("\t").count("111")) 
c = b.collect()
```

Could someone please clarify ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> (1) variable a will be saved as a RDD variable **containing** the expected txt file content

(Highlighting mine) Not really. The line just **describes** what will happen **after** you execute an action, i.e. the RDD variable does **not** contain the expected txt file content.

The RDD describes the partitions that, when an action is called, become tasks that will read their parts of the input file.

> (2) The driver node breaks up the work into tasks and each task contains information about the split of the data it will operate on. Now these Tasks are assigned to worker nodes.

Yes, but only when an action is called which is `c=b.collect()` in your case.

> (3) when collection action (i.e collect() in our case) is invoked, the results will be returned to the master from different nodes, and saved as a local variable c.

YES! That's the most dangerous operation memory-wise since all the Spark executors running *somewhere* in the cluster start sending data back to the driver.

> Now I want to understand what difference below code makes

Quoting the documentation of [sc.textFile](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext@textFile(path:String,minPartitions:Int):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]):

> **textFile(path: String, minPartitions: Int = defaultMinPartitions): RDD[String]** Read a text file from HDFS, a local file system (available on all nodes), or any Hadoop-supported file system URI, and return it as an RDD of Strings.

Quoting the documentation of [sc.parallelize](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext@parallelize[T](seq:Seq[T],numSlices:Int)(implicitevidence$1:scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T]):

> **parallelize[T](seq: Seq[T], numSlices: Int = defaultParallelism)(implicit arg0: ClassTag[T]): RDD[T]** Distribute a local Scala collection to form an RDD.

The difference is with the datasets - files (for `textFile`) while a local collection (for `parallelize`). Either does the same things under the covers, i.e. they both build a description of how to access the data that are going to be processed using transformations and an action.

The main difference is therefore the source of the data.

Comment: I have an rdd with list of file names in a folder obtained using parallelise function and I am using foreach to read each files in an rdd then will the files be rear in parallel and by this can I perform any transformation on each individual files parallely..

Comment: @BARATH That deserves a separate question (and think one was asked already - search stackoverflow). Just to give you one, you can have a parallel and distributed computation in Spark depending on the number of records (files in your case) per partition. Partitions are the parallel tasks. The more the more parallel computation.

Comment: @Jacek Laskowski - sc.textFile() I understand. How does sc.parallelize(<collection>) work? The collection is created in the driver program itself. How is (are) the RDD (partitions) created from this collection distributed to the worker nodes? Do the  partitions first get distributed to the worker nodes and then tasks scheduled on the executors on those nodes? Or, do the individual tasks have their corr. RDD partition already bundled in it when the DAGScheduler->TaskScheduler created in the driver program intend to distribute  the tasks to the executors on the worker nodes?